# Watching folder for arrival of files to batch process?

Tags: ogr2ogr, batch

Is there a way to maintain a watch on a folder to enable automatic file type conversion? I have a program that dumps DXF files - I batch convert all files to both shapefile and mapinfo format.

It would be great to automate it further so that it automatically undertakes the conversions.

Comment: You might get a better response on StackOverflow. You also need to specify what operating system you are running on. This is more of an Op System related question, requiring a cron task to poll the folder.

Comment: I agree with @MarkC.  The solution to this will be the same as if you just did a system copy rather than an ogr2ogr so I think you will be better deleting your question here and researching/asking it at Stack Overflow instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can try out

- a dedicated tool called [Batyr](http://geops.de/blog/143-batyr-demand-synchronization-vector-data-postgis-database) for this purpose (more PostGis oriented than GDAL)
- generic tools like ETL with spatial abilities (Talend with Spatial Extension, GeoKettle,...) that can watch your folder
- [Inotify based tools](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify) (On Unix based OS)
- a command line tool like [Watchdog](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog)

I will not go further as @mark-c mentioned, it's more a system question than GIS related.